# Redshift toggles on and off (flickering)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, screen

I installed redshift on ubuntu 16.04 to reduce blue light. However, when I turn it on, it toggles on and off every 1-2 seconds continuously. I ran it in verbose mode (redshift -v) and this is the output:

```
Temperatures: 3500K at day, 3500K at night
Solar elevations: day above 3.0, night below -6.0
Brightness: 1.00:1.00
Gamma (Daytime): 1.000, 1.000, 1.000
Gamma (Night): 1.000, 1.000, 1.000
Status: Enabled
Period: Night
Color temperature: 3500K
Brightness: 1.00
```

The location is set as well.

Answer (score 52):

I had the same problem. For me, I had a redshift-gtk process running in the background and didn't know, so when I tried to launch a new one after making some changes, they began fighting with each other. One making the changes I wanted, one then reapplying the default config and causing what seemed like a flicker. What I did was:

- alter settings via the ~/.config/redshift.conf file. (example here: http://jonls.dk/redshift/)
- kill the running redshift process(es) `pgrep redshift | xargs -n1 kill -9`
- restart redshift `redshift-gtk & disown`

You should see an icon in the upper right that looks like a light bulb that will allow control of reshift. And hopefully no more flickering!

Answer (score 18):

If you are running Gnome or have updated to Ubuntu 18.04, then the Night Light feature may be conflicting with Redshift. Try disabling Night Light in Settings -> Displays.

Comment: Thank you, this saved me! :)

Comment: On KDE there is a similar feature named Night Color, under Display and Monitor in System Settings.

Comment: Same issue on Ubuntu 22.04, this saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem also. For me I had to use a combination of-

- reset the screen `redshift -x`
- then I used user.friendly's `pgrep redshift | xargs -n1 kill -9` to kill the process

For some reason my system decided to reapply the redshift hue after a couple of seconds of using `redshift -x`.

So... I had to reset then kill the process with the above kill command whilst it wasn't set.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31254398)